# How to simplify matrix exponential expression

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Suppose $\boldsymbol{M}$ is an $n \times n$ non-singular matrix, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is a $1 \times n$ row vector, $\boldsymbol{1}$ is a $n \times 1$ column vector of ones. Is there a simpler way to write the following in terms of $x$?
$$(\boldsymbol{\beta}e^{\boldsymbol{M}x}\boldsymbol{1})^2 $$

I ask because I want to integrate the above with respect to $x$:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(\boldsymbol{\beta}e^{\boldsymbol{M}x}\boldsymbol{1})^2 dx$$

Comment: Rewrite the integral as $\beta\left(\int_a^be^{xM}\mathbf1\mathbf1^\top e^{xM^\top}dx\right)\beta^\top$. The integral inside the bracket is then a solution to a Lyapunov equation of the form $MA+AM^\top=B$. When no two eigenvalues of $M$ sum to zero, the equation is uniquely solved by $\operatorname{vec}(A)
=(I\otimes M+M\otimes I)^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(B)$. Hence your original integral is $\beta A\beta^\top$.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your comment. I'm afraid I don't follow at all, though. Could you elaborate with a longer answer please? 
(1) Why is it that I can write 
$\int_{a}^{b}(\boldsymbol{\beta}e^{\boldsymbol{M}x}\boldsymbol{1})^2 dx$ 
as 
$\boldsymbol{\beta}(\int_{a}^{b}e^{\boldsymbol{M}x}\boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{1}^T {e^{\boldsymbol{M}x} }^T
dx)\beta^T$. (2) I don't understand how Lyapunov relates to my problem. (3) You state my original integral is $\beta A \beta^\top$, though I don't understand how you eleminated the matrix exponential and nor how $A$ will be in terms of $x$.

Comment: (1) Because a $1\times1$ matrix is equal to its transpose. (2) & (3) Please look up Lyapunov equation from Wikipedia or from some textbooks on advanced linear algebra or control theory. If you call the integrand $f(x)$, then $Mf(x)+f(x)M^\top$ has an explicit antiderivative. Hence you can calculate $B=\int_a^b Mf(x)+f(x)M^\top dx$ explicitly. But then $B=MA+AM^\top$ where $A=\int_a^bf(x)dx$.

Comment: @user1551 Ah! This is great, makes so much more sense now. Thank you. However the only final things I am unsure on are as follows. Wikipedia states the solution is the integral from 0 to $\infty$, does the result still hold if we have some $a\neq0$ and $b\neq\infty$?

Furthermore, earlier i wrote ${e^{Mx}}^T$, by which I meant $({e^{Mx}})^T$. Is it fair to say that $({e^{Mx}}^T)=({e^{M^Tx}})$? It's not clear to me that that is always true.

Comment: Regarding my second comment. Generally, we have $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ (I believe?), therefore I presume it's true that  $(A+B+C+D...)^T=(A^T+B^T+C^T+D^T...)$. Therefore by writing the definition of a matrix exponential, we see that $({e^{Mx}}^T)=({e^{M^Tx}})$ must be true. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I wonder if you have any more thoughts on this @user1551?